# How to add double quotes to the dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, formatting

It is necessary to add double quotes for the key and value in the dictionary.
I tried to do it with regular expressions, but I’m not good at it (
The dictionary can be of two types 1) a = {x: 2, y: 1, z: -3, b: 1}
2) a = {x: 226/185, y: 9/37, z: -409/185, b: 133/185}
We need to find a universal solution for both types.

```
gg={x: 2, y: 1, z: -3, b: 1}
gg1={x: 226/185, y: 9/37, z: -409/185, b: 133/185}


nn="{x: 2, y: 1, z: -3, b: 1}"
nn2="{x: 226/185, y: 9/37, z: -409/185, b: 133/185}"

yy=re.sub(r'(\w*): (\d*)',r'"\1": "\2"',nn)
yy2=re.sub(r'(\w*): (\d*)',r'"\1": "\2"',nn2)
print(yy)
print(yy2)
```

{"x": "2", "y": "1", "z": ""-3, "b": "1"}
{"x": "226"/185, "y": "9"/37, "z": ""-409/185, "b": "133"/185}

Comment: Try `r'(\w*):\s*(-?\d[\d/.]*)'` regex

Comment: It looks like XY problem. I guess you want to create a JSON. Is that the case? Also where dictionary comes from - i.e. second "kind" of dict has fractional values (e.g. 226/185)

Comment: if you are trying to create json, try `import json; json.dumps(your_dict)` which should handle it

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
nn="{x: 2, y: 1, z: -3, b: 1}"

nn2="{x: 226/185, y: 9/37, z: -409/185, b: 133/185}"
dict_str = lambda data : re.sub(r'(\w+):\s*(-?\d[\d/.]*)',r'"\1": "\2"',data)
for i in [nn,nn2] :
    var1=dict_str(i)
    print(var1)
    # if you want an actual dictionary from var1 you can uncomment the lines  below
    #var2 = var1.replace('{','').replace('}','').replace('"','')
    #var3 ={ j.split(':')[0] : j.split(':')[1] for j in [ k for k in 
        #var1.split(',') ] }
    #print(var3)
```