# python RegEx json Double quotes

Tags: json, regex, python-3.x

I got a json through the spider, but the json format has a problem, name:value, the name is missing double quotes. like this:

```
   { listInfo:[{title:'it is title',url:'http://test.com',imgurl:'http://test.com',imgurl2:'',abstract:'',source:'',pubtime:'2019-05-22 11:47:24'},{title:'xx',url:'http://test.com/1.htm',imgurl:'http://test.com',imgurl2:'',abstract:'',source:'',pubtime:'2019-05-22 07:54:46'}]}
```

I want add double quotes in "name",and need to exclude String of [http { ...]

```
{ "listInfo":[{"title":'it is "title"',"url":'http://test.com',...
```

I tryed this but it is not work

```
#(.*?)\:(.*?)\n'
pattern = re.compile(r'^((?![http]\").)*\:(.*?)\n', re.MULTILINE )
content = content.replace(pattern.search(content).group(1),'\"'+pattern.search(content).group(1).strip()+'\"')
```

I also tryed 
       [How to add double quotes to the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452542/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-the-dictionary)

```
content = '''
{ listInfo:[{title:'it is title',url:'http://test.com',
imgurl:'http://test.com',imgurl2:'',abstract:'',source:'',
pubtime:'2019-05-22 11:47:24'},{title:'xx',url:'http://test.com/1.htm',
imgurl:'http://test.com',imgurl2:'',abstract:'',source:'',pubtime:'2019-05-22 07:54:46'}]}
'''

# dict_str = lambda data : re.sub(r'(\w+):\s*(-?\d[\d/.]*)',r'"\1": "\2"',data)
dict_str = lambda data : re.sub(r'(\w+):(.*?)\n',r'"\1": "\2"',data)
for i in [content] :
    var1=dict_str(i)
    print(var1)
```

the result is look like:

```
{ "listInfo": "[{title:'it is title',url:'http://test.com',""imgurl": "'http://test.com',imgurl2:'',abstract:'',source:'',""pubtime": "'2019-05-22 11:47:24'},{title:'xx',url:'http://test.com/1.htm',""imgurl": "'http://test.com',imgurl2:'',abstract:'',source:'',pubtime:'2019-05-22 07:54:46'}]}"
```

Who knows how to write regEx.
Thinks!

I used a comparative method to solve it.

```
script = script.replace('abstract','\"abstract\"')
...
```

:(

Comment: Your first example is a json string?, it actually looks similar to a dictionary, but an invalid one

Comment: no,Spider to get it

Comment: I am not sure what that means! Can you correct your examples to make them more clear

Comment: update my qustion(sorry ,My English is not  good)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add double quotes to the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452542/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-the-dictionary)

Comment: @Aaron_ab Thinks very much,but, I want to exclude String of [http],and the result is this:{ "listInfo": "[{title:'it is title',url:... the 'title' and 'url' is not to add double quotes ,use:r'(\w+):(.*?)\n'